# CSV file created by shell script is in binary encoding, need it to be utf-8 or ISO-8859-1

Tags: bash, shell

I'm aggregating CSV files in a shell script into one bigger CSV file. The original CSV files are encoded in utf-16le (when I use `file -I`), but the CSV file that gets created is in binary encoding (when I check again with `file -I`). The code I'm using is

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ \.csv$ ]]; then
      tail -n +2 "$file" >> aggregate.csv
    fi
```

How can I get the aggregate csv file to have utf-8 encoding? Anything I try with `iconv` turns the file into 0 bytes or a complete mess

`iconv -f binary -t UTF-8 aggregate.csv > a.csv` returns conversion from binary unsupported

`iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF-8 aggregate.csv > a.csv` gives a CSV file with a bunch of random characters inserted, and a.csv is still binary encoded according to `file -I`

`iconv -f UTF16le -t UTF-8 aggregate.csv > a.csv` does the same as above

and finally, `iconv -f UTF16le -t UTF8 aggregate.csv > aggregate.csv returns a file with 0 bytes

Edit: The input files are all utf-16le and should all be the same format b/c they are app download reports downloaded from the Google Play developer site. As per eckes' suggestion, I tried converting each file to UTF-8 before aggregating and it works! Thanks

Comment: What have you tried with `iconv`?  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39256999/edit) with additional details.  Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to normalize the input files first. I think tail itself does not care about the encoding, so iconv them from utf-16 to utf-8 with no BOM and append them with tail.

Comment: I've edited it with more information and the `iconv` that i've tried.